# Convert Nested JSON Structure to a certain Object Format in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have an input JSON structure like this:

```
{
  "permissions_list": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "module": "Manufacture",
      "view": true,
      "add": true,
      "edit": true,
      "delete": false,
      "print": true,
      "permission_details": [
        {
          "id": 0,
          "sub_module": "Formula Template",
          "view": true,
          "add": true,
          "edit": true,
          "delete": true,
          "print": true
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "module": "Setting",
      "view": true,
      "add": false,
      "edit": true,
      "delete": false,
      "print": true,
      "permission_details": [
        {
          "rowId": 0,
          "id": 0,
          "sub_module": "User",
          "view": true,
          "add": true,
          "edit": true,
          "delete": true,
          "print": true
        },
        {
          "rowId": 1,
          "id": 1,
          "sub_module": "Role",
          "view": true,
          "add": true,
          "edit": true,
          "delete": true,
          "print": true
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to convert this JSON structure into the following format:

```
{
  manufacture: {
    label: "Manufacture",
    permissions: [
      "view",
      "add",
      "edit",
      "delete",
      "print"
    ],
    child: {
      formula_template: {
        label: "Formula Template",
        permissions: [
          "view",
          "delete",
          "add",
          "edit",
          "print"
        ]
      }, 
    }
  },
  setting: {
    label: "Setting",
    permissions: [
      "view",
      "add",
      "edit",
      "delete",
      "print"
    ],
    child: {
      user: {
        label: "User",
        permissions: [
          "view",
          "delete",
          "add",
          "edit",
          "print"
        ]
      },
      role: {
        label: "Role",
        permissions: [
          "view",
          "delete",
          "add",
          "edit",
          "print"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried to write JavaScript code to achieve this transformation, but I'm encountering some challenges. Here's what I've attempted so far:

each one of these value might be true or false:
`"view": true, "add": true, "edit": false, "delete": true, "print": false`
if they true we have an array like this

`permissions: [ "view", "add", "delete", ],`

```
data.reduce(
            (acc: { [key: string]: any }, array: any) => {
                const parentPermission = [
                    'view',
                    'add',
                    'edit',
                    'delete',
                    'print',
                ]
                    .map((act: string) => array[act] && act)
                    .filter(Boolean);

                const childPermission = array.permission_details.map(
                    (sub: any) => {
                        const key = sub.sub_module
                            .toLowerCase()
                            .split(' ')
                            .join('_');
                        const permissionsArr = [
                            'view',
                            'add',
                            'edit',
                            'delete',
                            'print',
                        ]
                            .map((act: string) => sub[act] && act)
                            .filter(Boolean);
                        return {
                            [key]: {
                                label: sub.sub_module,
                                permissions: permissionsArr,
                            },
                        };
                    },
                );

                const key = array.module.toLowerCase().split(' ').join('_');
                acc[key] = {
                    label: array.module,
                    permissions: parentPermission,
                    child: childPermission,
                };

                return acc;
            },
            {},
        );
```

In my code I wrote this part hardcode that might be change its depend on data I get
`[ 'view', 'add', 'edit', 'delete', 'print', ]`
How could I dynamic this part
Maybe in the future, something new will be added or something will change.

I would appreciate any guidance or assistance in achieving this transformation. Thank you!

Comment: Please edit your post so that you have grammatically correct sentences.  "How could I dynamic this part Maybe in the future, something new will be added or something will change." is not a coherent question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reduce arrays to objects like this.

Also you shouldn't include `false` permission I guess.

Also a general note you should keep any list data as arrays, not objects, since manipulating objects like filtering, mapping, sorting is kinda hard opposite to arrays having all methods for that out of the box.

Also if you have other boolean values in objects besides permissions you should also check the property keys.

I hope this will give a good start for a perfect solution, don't hesitate to tweak to your specific needs.

```js
const transform = list => list.reduce((r, item) => {
  const label = item.module ?? item.sub_module;
  r[label.toLowerCase().replace(' ', '_')] = {
    label, 
    permissions: Object.keys(item).reduce((r, key) => (item[key] === true && r.push(key), r), []),
    ...item.permission_details ? {child: transform(item.permission_details)} : {}
  };
  return r;
}, {});

console.log(transform(data.permissions_list));
```

```html
<script> 

const data = {
  "permissions_list": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "module": "Manufacture",
      "view": true,
      "add": true,
      "edit": true,
      "delete": false,
      "print": true,
      "permission_details": [
        {
          "id": 0,
          "sub_module": "Formula Template",
          "view": true,
          "add": true,
          "edit": true,
          "delete": true,
          "print": true
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "module": "Setting",
      "view": true,
      "add": false,
      "edit": true,
      "delete": false,
      "print": true,
      "permission_details": [
        {
          "rowId": 0,
          "id": 0,
          "sub_module": "User",
          "view": true,
          "add": true,
          "edit": true,
          "delete": true,
          "print": true
        },
        {
          "rowId": 1,
          "id": 1,
          "sub_module": "Role",
          "view": true,
          "add": true,
          "edit": true,
          "delete": true,
          "print": true
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
</script>
```